# Passing data from the test context to a Jest mocked ES6 class

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have a test framework that I'm building for my project. In the test file, we have something like this:

```
//myTest.tsx
import {MyFooDependency} from 'path/to/MyFooDependency';
jest.mock('path/to/MyFooDependency');

describe('foo tests', () => {
  it('foo', async () => {
    const myObjUnderTest = new MyObj();
    const res = await myObjUnderTest.testMethod();
    expect(res).toBe(expectedResult);
  }
}
```

I have a manual mock like so:

```
//path/to/__mocks__/MyFooDependency.tsx

export class MyFooDependency {
  //mock implementation of class
  const mockData = [
      {usefulDataKey: "fooVal1"},
      {usefulDataKey: "fooVal2"},
      {usefulDataKey: "fooVal3"},
    ];

  let calls = 0;
  getData() {
    const ret = mockData[calls];
    calls++;
    return ret;
  }
}
```

the object under test eventually calls into `MyFooDependency` and gets some data returned. With the above code, the `MyFooDependency` that is used is my manual mock.

I would like to inject data from my test *into* the `MyFooDependency` mock, to drive the behavior. So in this example I'd like the test to know about the `mockData` object, and inject that (which will change per test) into the `MyFooDependency` manual mock.

How can I inject this data into the manual mock?